# Sharepoint 2010 My-sites Active Directory connection error

Tags: active-directory, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

There is a good tutorial of creation of Sharepoint 2010 My-sites [here](http://www.helloitsliam.com/archive/2010/01/18/sharepoint-2010-%E2%80%93-my-sites.aspx).
In my environment I can't get the connection to Active Directory work, as it fails with:
"An operation error occurred."

There is a text "For Active Directory connections to work, this account must have directory sync rights." but I don't know what that means...

My question is: There is nothing in the Event Log. Where is the error-log? :-)

Comment: Is your server that hosts the MySite sites connected to an Active Directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748656(office.14).aspx) is the documentation for SharePoint 2010 logging. Basically, if you go into:

```
Central Admin -> Monitoring -> Configure Diagnostic Logging
```

The Trace Log section "Path" box will tell you where your logs are located.

This screen will also allow you to increase the logging level if the default levels don't show you any useful messages.